# Hiding Gear From Sensors

Tags: shadowrun-sr5

I have a player who wants to buy clothing/armor with built-in pockets that have a lining of fabric that helps to hide gear from sensors (like a gun or explosives). I like the idea, but I can't seem to find rules anywhere for anything like this.

Are there rules for materials that block sensors?

Comment: Would *fabric that helps to hide gear from sensors* not increase suspicion? Maybe I can't see whats hidden but the fact that my sight is blocked should raise the alarm. Might not be the case for chem sniffers / and or metal detectors and the like but typical bodyscanners and similar should not be fooled.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Universal Mirror Material, in Run and Gun's armor customizations, pg 86, causes Noise penalties to be applied for stuff that's hidden under the armor.  While that's most immediately useful for protecting it from hackers, remember that most scanners/sensors (actually ANY wireless devices, SR5 core pg. 421) have to fight against Noise, too.

Also, common sense would say that the UMM which blocks signals should probably increase the difficulty to spot the item under the armor using a sensor, although it isn't specifically spelled out in the rules.